# Difference between xul-ext-ublock-origin package and ublock origin Chrome extension?

Tags: apt, google-chrome, chrome-extension

What is the difference (in functionality and use) between the Ubuntu package [xul-ext-ublock-origin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xul-ext-ublock-origin), and the Chrome extension [ublock origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm)?

Comment: The former seems, by virtue of `xul`, to be something associated with Firefox/Thunderbird. All the same, if I want ublock origin for Firefox, I'd get it from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and delete the last sentence because that could lead to the question being closed because it is soliciting opinion. See https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @DKBose OK, done.

Comment: @DKBose: Asking for objective advantages and disadvantages is not primarily opinion-based. Asking "which is better?" would be.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I commented because there was a close vote for that same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xul-ext-ublock-origin` package in repository is for "Firefox" browser (Also "thunderbird" or "Seamonky") :

```
$ apt-cache show xul-ext-ublock-origin | grep -i depends
Depends: firefox (>= 24.0) | thunderbird (>= 31.0) | seamonkey (>= 2.21)
```

So you should compare it with [ublock-origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/), there is no difference in my opinion except when you install the package it will be available system wide to all users.

The other thing you should pay attention to is the version of add-on, in Ubuntu repository it's between 1.6.6 to 1.10.4 however the last version is 1.12.4.

```
 $ rmadison xul-ext-ublock-origin 

 xul-ext-ublock-origin | 1.6.6+dfsg-1  | xenial/universe  | all
 xul-ext-ublock-origin | 1.9.10+dfsg-2 | yakkety/universe | all
 xul-ext-ublock-origin | 1.10.4+dfsg-1 | zesty/universe   | all
 xul-ext-ublock-origin | 1.10.4+dfsg-1 | artful/universe  | all
```

it might not be that much important cause after first run it will be updated to last version.

And the other one which you mentioned is just a port of same thing for Chrome browser.

Comment: If you run `apt policy xul-ext-ublock-origin`, you'll see version 1.6 for xenial whereas the version I have from mozilla addons is 1.12. I haven't installed the xul version and so I don't know if it will be as up to date.

Comment: Yeah, that's  true :-) however it's going to get update I guess.

Comment: While that is possible, do you know whether individual users would be able to have their own settings for ublock when it is installed system-wide?

Comment: The configuration should be saved separately per user,  just like Ubuntu modifications add-on.